# Optimize inversing word while capitalize word after space function

Tags: c++, c

```
void inverse(char *string) 
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = strlen(string) - 1;
    char temp;

    //Inverse the order
    while ( i < j )
    {
        temp = *( string + i );

        *( string + i ) = *( string + j );
        *( string + j ) = temp;

        i++;
        j--;
    }   

    //Capitalize letter after space
    while( *string != '\0')
    {
        if ( *( string ) == ' ' && *( string + 1 ) != ' ')
        {
            *( ++string ) = toupper( *( string ) );
        }
        string++;
    }
}
```

I just want to know if there is a better way to make this output, especially produce same output with less lines of code

Comment: Instead of trying to optimise you should try to get it right: The capitalisation invokes undefined behaviour, because it is not clear whether the increment on the lhs happens after or before the access to the same variable on the rhs. You also miss the first character and try to capitalise the null terminator when the string ends with a space (which probably isn't harmful, but still).

Comment: In my opinion, the function should be split into two separate functions: one to reverse the string and another one to capitalise the first letters of words. Each of the functions does one clearly defined thing and you can then call them independently.

Comment: You are close. Your inverse is fine, you handle both ends during each iteration. Your capitalize is fine as well. You can always unroll the loop and search 4-chars at a time to pickup some performance, but if your strings are relatively short (less than 1000 chars or so), the benefits are negligible. For anything longer, you will see gains by unrolling. (look at the `strlen` source code for an example) -- Agree needs to be 2 functions.

Comment: `std::reverse( string, string+strlen(string) );`  will be at least as fast as anything you can write.

Comment: Your "capitalize after space" loop is broken for a string like " a".  Ignoring the undefined behaviour as to exactly when `string` is incremented, you will increment `string` (to point to `\0`) then increment it again, and run off the end of the passed in string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some general tips to cleanup and reduce the number of lines of code:

1. Use `for` loops instead of `while` loops. This

```
int i = 0;
while ( i < 10 )
{
    // loop body
    i++;
}
```

is better written as

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    // loop body
}
```

2. Declare variables when you first use them. For example, the declaration of `temp` can be done inside the loop.

3. Use array syntax instead of pointer arithmetic. For example, this

```
*( string + i ) = *( string + j );
```

is better written as

```
string[i] = string[j];
```

With that in mind the code to reverse the string could be written as

```
for ( int i = 0, j = strlen(string)-1; i < j; i++, j-- )
{
    char temp = string[i];
    string[i] = string[j];
    string[j] = temp;
}
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, the code to capitalize the first letter of words has some issues. The algorithm in the question advances the `string` pointer until it points to a space character, and then capitalizes the character at address `string+1`.

An alternative algorithm keeps a copy of the previous character. If the previous character was a space, then the current character is capitalized. Here's an implementation of that algorithm:

```
for ( char oldc = ' '; *string != '\0'; string++ )
{
    if ( oldc == ' ' )
        *string = toupper(*string);
    oldc = *string;
}
```

Note that this will capitalize the first character in the string, and any character that follows a space. If you specifically only want to capitalize characters that follow a space, and not the first character, then change the initialization of `oldc` so that is doesn't start as a space, e.g.

```
for ( char oldc = 'a'; *string != '\0'; string++ )
```

Comment: for ( int i = 0, j = strlen(string)-1; i < j; i++, j-- )
{
    char temp = string[i];
    string[i] = string[j];
    string[j] = temp;
}

for this part, i thought it's better to put the char temp outside of the loop, because u define the type of temp( in this case char) every time you do looping.....or maybe my argument invalid?

Comment: @KevinMogi That's a common misconception. But what actually happens is that the compiler keeps track of how many variables are declared in the entire function, and allocates enough space on the stack for all the variables. So it doesn't matter where the variables are declared, the space is allocated once at the beginning of the function. You can confirm this by looking at the assembly code that the compiler generates. Note that I'm talking about gcc or clang, there may be some lousy compilers out there that don't do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you can optimize it greatly. Let's review the logic first.

We need to have each character that follows the space be uppercased in the result string. What does that mean? That means that in the original string such characters are located before the space. Thus, we have the criteria to find those in the original string and actually make them uppercase even before swapping. This renders second loop unnessessary -- we can do all in one.

Here's the example how it can be implemented:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void transform(char* s)
{
  char temp;

  char* endPtr = s + strlen(s) - 1;

  while (s < endPtr)
  {
    /* 
      converting left hand part like 'c ' to 'C ' 
      so that after swap it turns to ' C' 
    */
    if (!isspace(*s) && isspace(*(s + 1)))
      *s = toupper(*s);

    /* same to the right side */
    if (isspace(*endPtr) && !isspace(*(endPtr - 1)))
      *(endPtr - 1) = toupper(*(endPtr - 1)); 

    /* swap */
    temp = *s;
    *s = *endPtr;
    *endPtr = temp;

    s++;
    endPtr--;
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  char str[] = "this is a demo string! the one and only  real demo string. crazy example ";

  transform(str);

  printf("'%s'\n", str);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can remove the temp variable while reversing using xor operation

```
    int end= strlen(string)-1;
    int start = 0;

    while( start<end )
    {
    string[start] ^= string[end];
    string[end] ^= string[start];
    string[start]^= string[end];

    ++start;
    --end;
    }
```

To capitalized each letter, try with code below:

```
char* reversestr = *string;
while( *reversestr != '\0')
{
    if (i==0 || *(reversestr - 1) ==' ' && *reversestr >= 'a' && *reversestr <= 'z')
           *reversestr = toupper(*reversestr);
    reversestr++;
}
```

I am not tested the code yet, but I think it should work.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant is XOR is not good idea?? and what about capitalized code??

Comment: The "XOR trick" is usually not faster on many modern architectures than just doing the swap with a temporary, but it's less general, more error-prone and is not immediately understandable.

Comment: It is usually *slower*.  Temporaries are cheap.  Memory access is expensive.